# Customizing Alert Template XML

Tags: alert, xml

I need to alter the Alerts Template for a particular list, but don't even know where to begin.

I know I need to make a copy of the xml file. Once I actually update the copy I need to execute some powershell and then restart the timer job. I also read something about needing to do something programatically, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any step by step documentation out there to help me out?

Thanks,
Ninel

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/how-to-create-custom-email-alert-template-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: What is it that you are doing to the alerts?

Comment: I would like to remove the heading and only display certain columns

Answer (score 1):

This should help you: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

regards,

KS