# Why does list form show crossed out text after editing?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2016, alert, edit-form

I created a list form with an alert setup to watch for changes.  After changes are made I receive an email that shows a line through previous text and the updated text next to it.  See image.  The cross outs are confusing to users.

Is there a way to prevent the edits/cross outs from appearing in the email?

[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint default list form?

Comment: Yes.  This is a default list form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the alert template by modifying the `Alerttemplates.xml` file as per your requirements.

On On-Premise SharePoint local server, the Alerttemplates.xml file is located at:

`Local_Drive\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14(15)\Template\XML` directory.

You can find more details at:

1. [SharePoint - Customize Email Alerts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0173bbc8-4c18-45eb-b21d-e80a5f551ef4/sharepoint-online-customize-email-alerts)
2. [Modifying the Appearance of Alerts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862021(v=office.14))
3. [How to create custom email alert template in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/how-to-create-custom-email-alert-template-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

**Please the following step:**

1.Go to **alerttemplates.xml** file located at ***"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML"***

[image]

2.Keep the copy of **alerttemplates.xml** for backup.

3.Edit **original alerttemplates.xml** file.

- Depending on your listtype make the limit length **1000**.
- If list is custom list edit the line under **GenericList** and so on.

`<Limit Len="1000" AutoHyperLinkNoEncoding="TRUE" MoreText="..."> <GetVar Name="OldValue#{Field}" /> </Limit>`

4.Run the following command in the **SharePoint Management Shell Window**

- iisreset

[image]

Comment: Will changing the alerttemplates.xml effect all lists?

Comment: Hi, C1TonyB. Does not affect all lists in SharePoint Server. You can refer to this article.http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/alert-template-from-scratch/